# Is there any achievement that gives out rewards?

Tags: achievements, diablo-iii

In World of Warcraft there are various achievements that give out a reward other than the Achievement Points, be it a [title](http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=46), a [pet](http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=5875), or a [mount](http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=2145). Is there something similar in Diablo III?

I know that pets and mounts won't be available in Sanctuary, but I was thinking about something  like a worthless item related to the lore, or a physical modification that has no impact on stats. I could even be happy with a stone that says "Hi!" with Deckard Cain's voice every time it's clicked!

Comment: Achievements may give more options for customizing your banner like in the Beta, including titles. Mounts and pets are not a part of Diablo 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are achievements that reward you with **shapes**, **patterns**, **sigils** and **accents** (images that appears on your [banner](http://www.diablowiki.net/Banner)).

Here is an example: [The Art of Conversation achievement](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/the-art-of-conversation).

Or this one: [Slice of Life achievement](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/slice-of-life).

Comment: And nothing else?

Comment: Still looking haha, but that should at least address the question of OP. Will add to this answer once I find more.

Comment: Yeah.. those "rewards" are pretty useless.

Comment: Kappei didn't ask me to make a judgment, so I didn't.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell if an achievement has a reward with just a glance in the achievement window. The small star icon indicates the number of rewards the achievement has.

In the example below, the Scavenger achievement has 6 rewards because there are 8 levels of the achievement. All but the first and seventh level have rewards.

[image]